# Convergence of integral of multiplication of two positive functions

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, continuity, improper-integrals

I have two functions $f, g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, that are continuous. I know that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(s) \, ds=C_1<\infty$, and $g(s)\le C_2$, with $C_1> 0$ and $C_2\ge0$, for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$.

For me, it is true that
$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(s)g(s) \, ds\le C_3<\infty$, with $C_3\ge0$. This statement would come from the fact that $f(s)g(s)\le C_2f(s)$, and then integrating on both sides.

This seems to be trivial, but I don't know if I should have additional conditions on the functions $f$ and $g$ so the previous statement is true. Any insights on this will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Answer (score -1):

g(s) could be equal to a constant value per your statement then the integral would not be bounded.
To be true g(s) integral must be bounded also.

Comment: This is not correct. $$0 \le \int_{\Bbb{R}} f(x)g(x)\,dx \le \int_{\Bbb{R}} C_2 f(x)\,dx = C_2\int_{\Bbb{R}} f(x)\,dx = C_1 C_2 <\infty.$$ That $f$ and $g$ are positive was crucial here since it allowed us to simply bound $fg$ above.

Comment: Yup, I should keep quiet.  Thanks

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself. Most of us on here have made mistakes (including myself - I've made lots). That's part of math. Take it as a learning experience.

Comment: Thank you, Cameron. It was very helpful.